# Storing Data on the disk in Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I am trying to implement an offline cache. I have created a `LocalFeedImageDataStore` that should persist data to disk and also allow it to be fetched at a later time.

However I am getting an error on insert and an error on retrieve if I try to append a path to my cache location.

If I use:

`FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

as my `storeURL` it works.

If I use:
`FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("feed/1b3c2a72-9720-44ac-b006-a1131793958e")`

I can an error and the operation does not save.

```
public final class LocalFeedImageDataStore: FeedImageDataStore {

  private let storeURL: URL
  private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "LocalFeedImageDataStore", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent)

  public init(storeURL: URL) {
    self.storeURL = storeURL
  }

  public func insert(_ data: Data, for url: URL, then completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlForData = makeCacheURL(storeURL, for: url)
    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
      do {
        try data.write(to: urlForData, options: .atomic)
        completion(.success(()))
      } catch {
        print("INSERT ERROR", error)
        completion(.failure(error))
      }
    }
  }

  public func retrieve(dataForURL url: URL, then completion: @escaping (Result<Data?, Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlForData = makeCacheURL(storeURL, for: url)
    print(urlForData)
    queue.async {
      do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlForData)
        completion(.success(data))
      } catch {
        print("FETCH ERROR", error)
        completion(.failure(error))
      }
    }
  }
}

private extension LocalFeedImageDataStore {
  func makeCacheURL(_ baseURL: URL, for imageURL: URL) -> URL {
    let encodedImageURL = Data(imageURL.path.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    return baseURL.appendingPathComponent(encodedImageURL)
  }
}
```

Comment: How big can be your cache? If it's small you can use `UserDefaults.standard` and store base64 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder is not present to add file

> The file “1b3c2a72-9720-44ac-b006-a1131793958e” doesn’t exist

To fix this create a folder and your image

```
public func insert(_ data: Data, for url: URL, then completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlForData = makeCacheURL(storeURL, for: url)
    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        do {
            try createFeedFolder()
            let filePath = newPath.appendingPathComponent("1b3c2a72-9720-44ac-b006-a1131793958e", isDirectory: false)
            try data.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
            completion(.success(()))
        } catch {
            print("INSERT ERROR", error)
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

private func createFeedFolder() throws {
    let filemanger = FileManager.default
    if let path = filemanger.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("feed", isDirectory: true)
        do {
            if !filemanger.fileExists(atPath: newPath.absoluteString) {
                try filemanger.createDirectory(at: newPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
        } catch { throw error }
    }
}
```